# Django "Exception has occurred: ImproperlyConfigured Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured..." even after setting in manage.py

Tags: python, django, docker, python-venv

Sorry, I am a newbie in Django, so please comment if I have forgotten any important information.

I have set up my Django App following [this VSCode tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-python). In short, it teaches me to build a docker image of a Django App in Venv.

When I started to run with VSCode, an error occurred saying that
`Exception has occurred: ImproperlyConfigured Requested setting DEBUG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`.

However, I have `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yiweis_blog.settings')` in my both `wsgi.py` and `manage.py`.

Meanwhile, when I attach a shell directly to the container, and run `python manage.py runserver`, it prints `Django version 3.1.1, using settings 'yiweis_blog.settings'`.

I have also tried to assign variable `yiweis_blog.settings` to `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in `dockerfile` and export the variable in terminal, but both of them still did not work.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

#### Append:

[Directory Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKBg3.png)

`yiweis_blog/yiweis_blog_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/Dockerfile`

(where yiweis_blog is my root folder where manage.py exists)

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

EXPOSE 8000

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install pip requirements
ADD requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Switching to a non-root user, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-user-rights
RUN useradd appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "yiweis_blog.wsgi"]
```

`yiweis_blog/manage.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'yiweis_blog.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  yiweisblog:
    image: yiweisblog
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

The result of `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 yiweis_blog.wsgi` is that:

```
appuser@7a4e96306663:/app$ gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 yiweis_blog.wsgi
[2020-10-19 07:11:24 +0000] [40] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2020-10-19 07:11:24 +0000] [40] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (40)
[2020-10-19 07:11:24 +0000] [40] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-10-19 07:11:24 +0000] [42] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 42
[2020-10-19 07:11:41 +0000] [40] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
```

After this, it just stuck and did not respond any more.

Comment: Please post your Dockerfile and manage.py files.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Which directory contains settings.py ?

Comment: hi, I have added the directory tree. `Settings.py` is in `yiweis_blog/yiweis_blog`

Comment: btw, really appreciate for your patience!

Comment: Have you run  django-admin startproject mysite and  python manage.py startapp myapp ?

Comment: The `.env` needs to be there in the same folder as the settings files, not the manage.py file.

Comment: Hi, I have used `run django-admin startproject mysite` to start the site project, but did not use `python manage.py startapp myapp` because I have not created any application yet.

Comment: Sadly, after adding a `.env` file in the same folder as `settings.py`, I still got the same error. 
BTW, I wrote `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=yiweis_blog.settings` in `.env`

Comment: Not sure what is happening under the hood with the VSCode extension. I notice a docker-compose.yml file has been created (by the VSCode extension I assume). If you post the contents of that it might shed some light on the problem. I'd also suggest attaching a shell to your container and run "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 yiweis_blog.wsgi" and see if you get an error.

Comment: Hi, I have checked and posted the docker-compose file but there is nothing special (at least from my very limited experience).

Comment: Yep, nothing special. The results of running gunicorn manually will hopefully be more interesting.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to attach a shell to the docker and the run the command you gave. I have posted the result above, because of the broken format in comment.

Comment: Looks like gunicorn is working fine when you run it manually. Perhaps run the container without using vscode and see what happens. Sorry, I know how to make Django and Docker work together but haven’t tried relying on vscode extensions to configure it.

Comment: Haha, yeah, this is also my first time trying writing django with vscode! I will try without vscode and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, surprisingly, I found that the problem is the entrance.

Comment: The program entrance I used is `django-admin`, not `manage.py`. And, as you know, the `django-admin` just does not set the environment variable

Comment: Though unfortunately, I have switched the project to Java Spring Framework which I am more familiar abhout

Answer (score 0):

Use this when utilizing F5 to runserver:

In manage.py

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '<appname>.settings'
```

instead of

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<appname>.settings")
```